# How to fix 'Magick: abort due to signal 6 (SIGABRT) "Abort". . .'

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I install passport in my laravel application but when I run the command

```
    php artisan passport:install
```

this error will show

```
    free(): invalid next size (fast)
    Magick: abort due to signal 6 (SIGABRT) "Abort"...
    Aborted (core dumped)
```

I tried to search but i didn't find the answer. Thank you!